# How to make Krave like shells?

Tags: restaurant-mimicry

How can I make a shell which has the same texture and taste as the shells on [Krave Cereal](https://www.kelloggskrave.com/home.html)?

I'm wanting to make my own with my own filings but have no idea where to start.

On the box it says they're made from oats,  rice, and wheat.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is an extremely mechanical process and not replicable at home.

Comment: I'm pretty sure she's right. Making a batter that could fairly closely duplicate the cereal might not be all that tough; after all, it appears to be mainly sugar and several grain flours, with some fats as emulsifiers, plus some coloring and (unidentified) flavoring. However, finding a way to shape the batter and bake it in a manner that would achieve the puffiness without giving the batter time to absorb the filling would probably involve an industrial processor and oven. It would have to bake very quickly to achieve the semi-impervious shell of the cereal.